# Maven2: is there a way to make the build fail in case of unknown profile parameter?

Tags: maven-2

We have three different maven2 profiles: prod, dev and test. One should be able to build with either one of those three profiles, or without any profile. In other words, following commands are acceptable:

```
mvn install
mvn -Pdev install
mvn -Ptest install
mvn -Pprod install
```

In case someone writes for example `mvn -Ppord install`, the build must fail. Is this possible to do?

P.s. I'm aware of http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireProperty.html but it seems that with require property it would not be possible to allow building without profile.

Comment: That sounds like something that would also help me. I haven't had a need for it. But would probably help avoid problems in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be possible with writing custom enforcer rule. If you'll look at [this example](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html) you'll see:

```
RuntimeInformation rti = (RuntimeInformation) helper.getComponent( RuntimeInformation.class );
```

this line gives you information about current runtime, following get MavenProject and active profiles list

```
MavenProject project = (MavenProject) helper.evaluate( "${project}" );
List profiles = new ArrayList( project.getActiveProfiles() );
```

If list of active profiles will be insuficient, you can get all profiles - example of this code can be found in [AllProfilesMojo.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/plugins/trunk/maven-help-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/help/AllProfilesMojo.java) from helper plugin.